# Issue with ansible dig Argument 'text' has incorrect type (expected str, got AnsibleUnicode)

Tags: ansible, dig

I try to do a dig of an hostname with ansible with this playbook:

```yaml
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
- hosts: localhost                                                                                                                           
  tasks:                                                                                                                                           
  - name: Simple A record (IPV4 address) lookup                                                                                     
    debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', 'www.google.com.')}}"
```

To have the same configuration and behavior on several laptop I'm running ansible in an alpine docker container.
I've installed python3 (v3.11.6) py3-dnspython net-tools bind-tools bind-libs and ansible (v2.14.5).
When I run the command: `ansible-playbook -i localhost test.yml` I've got the following error:

```bash
TASK [Simple A record (IPV4 address) lookup] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dig'. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: dns lookup illegal CLASS: Argument 'text' has incorrect type (expected str, got AnsibleUnicode). 
dns lookup illegal CLASS: Argument 'text' has incorrect type (expected str, got AnsibleUnicode)"}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

I've try to install dnspython with pip without success

Comment: I do suspect an incompatibility between your `community.general` collection and your Ansible version, as I cannot reproduce from the version you are giving. What does `ansible-galaxy collection list | grep community.general` gives you?

Comment: Are there some reasons that force you to use an outdated Ansible version? The most recent one is [2.16.3, with the latest 2.14 patch being 2.14.14](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tags).

Comment: The command  `ansible-galaxy collection list | grep community.general` returned that: ``` community.general             6.6.0                                                                                                              community.general       6.1.0    ``` . For the ansible version I used the one available through `apk add ansible`

Comment: I've managed by using the last alpine image to have ansible 2.16.1 and now the command return `community.general             7.5.1`. But I still have the error when I'm running the playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution, apparently as β.εηοιτ.βε said it was an incompatibility between ansible community general and python.
I've downgrade python version to 3.9.18 and use alpine 3.15 image.
Now it works